# RSA Encryption Problems

Tags: c#, math, encryption, cryptography, rsa

As part of my school project, I've tried to create the RSA encryption algorithm. I've followed the pseudocode and added all the operations, however after encrypting and decryption, the program does not return the original plaintext.

In my findCoPrime method, after some research I realised only certain numbers work. It is a temporary measure as I was trouble shooting however this did not seem to fix it. Not sure where I've gone wrong. My code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger x = generate2048Integer();
            BigInteger y = generate2048Integer();
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            BigInteger n = x * y;
            BigInteger phi = (x - 1) * (y - 1);
            BigInteger e = findCoPrime();
            BigInteger d = modInv(e, phi); 
            BigInteger key = RSAEncryption(77, e, n);
            BigInteger text = RSADecryption(key, d, n);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }

        public static BigInteger generate2048Integer()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                s += Convert.ToString(r.Next(0, 9));

            }
            return BigInteger.Parse(s);
        }

        public static BigInteger findCoPrime()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int pick = r.Next(0, 2);
            int l = 17;
            switch (pick)
            {
                case 0:
                    l = 17;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    l = 257;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    l = 65537;
                    break;
            }


            BigInteger temp = l;
            return temp;
        }

        public static BigInteger RandomIntegerBelow(BigInteger N)
        {
            byte[] bytes = N.ToByteArray();
            BigInteger R;
            Random random = new Random();
            do
            {
                random.NextBytes(bytes);
                bytes[bytes.Length - 1] &= (byte)0x7F; //force sign bit to positive
                R = new BigInteger(bytes);
            } while (R >= N);
            return R;
        }

        public static (BigInteger, BigInteger, BigInteger) egcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
        {
            if (a == BigInteger.Zero)
            {
                return (b, 0, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                BigInteger b_div_a;
                BigInteger b_mod_a;
                b_div_a = b / a;
                b_mod_a = mod(b, a);
                BigInteger g;
                BigInteger x;
                BigInteger y;
                (g, x, y) = egcd(b_mod_a, a);
                return (g, y - b_div_a * x, x);
            }
        }

        public static (BigInteger, BigInteger, BigInteger) xgcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
        {
            BigInteger x0 = 0;
            BigInteger x1 = 1;
            BigInteger y0 = 1;
            BigInteger y1 = 0;
            while (a != BigInteger.Zero)
            {
                BigInteger q;
                BigInteger b_div_a;
                BigInteger b_mod_a;
                b_div_a = b / a;
                b_mod_a = mod(b, a);
                q = b_div_a;
                a = b_mod_a;
                (y0, y1) = (y1, y0 - q * y1);
                (x0, x1) = (x1, x0 - q * x1);
            }
            return (b, x0, y0);
        }

        public static BigInteger modInv(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
        {
            BigInteger g;
            BigInteger x;
            BigInteger _;
            (g, x, _) = egcd(a, b);
            return mod(x, b);
        }
        public static BigInteger mod(BigInteger x, BigInteger m)
        {
            return (x % m + m) % m;
        }

        public static BigInteger RSAEncryption(BigInteger plaintext, BigInteger pubD, BigInteger n)
        {

            BigInteger rtrn = mod(Pow(plaintext, pubD), n);
            return rtrn;
        }

        public static BigInteger RSADecryption(BigInteger ciphertext, BigInteger privD, BigInteger n)
        {

            BigInteger rtrn = mod(Pow(ciphertext, privD), n);
            return rtrn;
        }


        public static BigInteger Pow(BigInteger value, BigInteger exponent)
        {
            BigInteger originalValue = value;
            while (exponent-- > 1)
                value = BigInteger.Multiply(value, originalValue);
            return value;
        }
     

   


    }
```

Comment: Find a reference implementation and compare to that.

Comment: RSA requires two random **primes**, not just two random integers. Most of the rest of code is messed up in one way or the other.  For legit large moduli the modular exponentiation code must use an algorithm that integrates multiplication and modular reduction steps as the result is being developed. You cannot do this by first computing the exponentiation and then performing the modulo operation.