# RSA Encryption Algorithm Problems

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

As part of my school project, I've tried to create the RSA encryption algorithm. I've followed the pseudocode and added all the operations, however after encrypting and decryption, the program does not return the original plaintext.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly int INTLIMIT = 2; //represents the max size in bit value
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger x = generate2048Integer();
            BigInteger y = generate2048Integer();
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            BigInteger n = x * y;
            BigInteger a = x - 1;
            BigInteger b = y - 1;
            BigInteger phi = BigInteger.Abs(a * b) / dgcd(a, b);
            BigInteger e = 65537;
            BigInteger d = newModInv(e, phi);
            BigInteger key = RSAEncryption(77, e, n);
            BigInteger text = RSADecryption(key, d, n);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }

        public static BigInteger generate2048Integer()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < INTLIMIT; i++)
            {
                s += Convert.ToString(r.Next(0, 9));

            }
            return BigInteger.Parse(s);
        }

       

       
        public static BigInteger dgcd(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
        {
            while (b != 0)
            {
                BigInteger t = b;
                b = mod(a, b);
                a = t;
            }
            return a;
        }

    

      

       
        public static BigInteger newModInv(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
        {
            BigInteger t = 0;
            BigInteger r = b;
            BigInteger newt = 1;
            BigInteger newr = a;
            while(newr != 0)
            {
                BigInteger q = r / newr;
                (t, newt) = (newt, t - q * newt);
                (r, newr) = (newr, r - q * newr);
            }
            if (r > 1)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if(t < 0)
            {
                t = t + b;
            }
            return t;
        }

        public static BigInteger mod(BigInteger x, BigInteger m)
        {
            return (x % m + m) % m;
        }

        public static BigInteger RSAEncryption(BigInteger plaintext, BigInteger pubD, BigInteger n)
        {

            BigInteger rtrn = mod(Pow(plaintext, pubD), n);
            return rtrn;
        }

        public static BigInteger RSADecryption(BigInteger ciphertext, BigInteger privD, BigInteger n)
        {

            BigInteger rtrn = mod(Pow(ciphertext, privD), n);
            return rtrn;
        }


        public static BigInteger Pow(BigInteger value, BigInteger exponent)
        {
            BigInteger originalValue = value;
            while (exponent-- > 1)
                value = BigInteger.Multiply(value, originalValue);
            return value;
        }





    }
}
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here, I believe it may be something to do with the Encryption though.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this exact question before, and the answer hasn't changed. RSA requires two random **primes**, not two merely random integers like you're generating. Also, if you ever fix the prime issue, you will have to use an modular exponentiation algorithm that integrates modulo calculations with multiplies to keep intermediate results less than the modulus. Otherwise you'll run out of memory and time trying to compute a \*\* b mod n for large sizes of n. HINT: just use the modPow that's builtin to BigInteger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RSA Encryption Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74545623/rsa-encryption-problems)